# TikZ picture's SI units wrap at incorrect magnitude

Tags: tikz-pgf, siunitx

I currently have an issue where the labeling of the y-axis is not as I would like it to be. Currently the labeling starts at 10 and wraps after 1000. Is there a way to have the labeling start at 1 and wrap after 100?

Can someone outline where my mistake is?

[image]

[Overleaf link.](https://www.overleaf.com/project/63b8122311634d2cceda5c1e)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents*}{gmm.csv}
x,manual_time,manual_memory,manual_error,impala_time,impala_memory,impala_error,impala-fix_time,impala-fix_memory,impala-fix_error,enzyme_time,enzyme_memory,enzyme_error,torch_time,torch_memory,torch_error
30,1,1409856,0.0,1,7570368,1.328272944021411e-14,1,8537088,1.328272944021411e-14,1,5080000,1.2354678474958976e-14,130,177531328,2.899777806651742e-15
60,2,1540928,0.0,3,8176576,1.8776855000741528e-13,2,9192448,1.8776855000741528e-13,2,9323392,1.8776855000741528e-13,129,179411328,4.2111715245608495e-14
150,5,1442688,0.0,7,17957952,4.2045319174289427e-13,8,16827584,4.2045319174289427e-13,7,19481536,4.2905581459185374e-13,140,283552896,7.640119609800198e-14
300,11,1377088,0.0,14,34014144,2.8436042738716444e-13,15,31147072,2.8436042738716444e-13,14,37307328,2.8436042738716444e-13,161,452968960,1.084077968323424e-13
330,7,1983296,0.0,6,33588608,2.5882150950782227e-14,7,15844416,2.5882150950782227e-14,5,16368768,2.417010205520519e-14,135,238619392,1.8731886315043515e-14
660,13,2147200,0.0,13,62964672,2.2418498542542217e-13,12,27968512,2.2418498542542217e-13,11,25051968,2.2418498542542217e-13,145,361078592,8.260059303211165e-14
1155,17,3031936,0.0,21,103482432,1.497925084279553e-14,15,28673088,1.8003881722357218e-14,14,25412608,5.997543098760249e-14,144,288566400,5.367407238477746e-14
1200,44,1426240,0.0,55,131531904,3.9152014963406145e-13,56,115524736,3.9152014963406145e-13,55,145392768,4.0131786782637846e-13,257,546071680,7.974036694338897e-14
1650,34,2179968,0.0,34,154420416,3.63555831004538e-13,31,64340928,3.63555831004538e-13,26,60130304,3.837241477269316e-13,174,395219072,2.708944180085382e-14
2310,33,2966400,0.0,38,204014976,1.3722609993754605e-13,27,51889088,1.3722609993754605e-13,26,46875712,2.487454686672663e-13,160,346017472,5.808686864838819e-13
2805,32,4080512,0.0,45,241403392,2.9441807806984166e-14,24,42959936,4.32650956187999e-14,29,38290368,6.002139383402994e-13,156,309341440,2.293575453007941e-13
3300,68,2261888,0.0,66,306890240,3.7735476481537635e-13,63,126829888,3.7735476481537635e-13,55,118179008,4.0594072192595703e-13,234,598779520,1.219024881038422e-13
5610,67,3949440,0.0,95,478693312,7.66053886991358e-14,50,81740800,7.66053886991358e-14,61,71107712,5.805356195764944e-13,200,418869376,7.482903185973555e-13
5775,86,3376256,0.0,104,505645120,6.141915426417256e-14,71,125486336,6.141915426417256e-14,70,110904320,1.8181019008615925e-13,236,568370688,8.657579878064937e-13
10725,122,7193728,0.0,206,890817216,1.4493080668625627e-13,69,83985472,1.155742168634788e-13,78,72221760,1.595559233604187e-12,219,440652224,6.6275873678023345e-12
11550,183,3621952,0.0,231,1008159488,1.5242747564090773e-13,146,247793024,1.5242747564090773e-13,148,219104576,2.5512925105886097e-13,363,985100736,2.3581137043038325e-13
13200,288,3032192,0.0,291,1221020928,3.469290385312999e-13,255,500582336,3.469290385312999e-13,229,466454400,3.469290385312999e-13,573,1735125120,6.536993168992922e-13
14025,178,4686912,0.0,266,1190906880,6.578071420904053e-14,134,198526208,6.017408793468348e-14,165,172180736,1.0480477276455908e-12,331,771742528,7.562284132234254e-13
21450,237,7718016,0.0,450,1774883008,2.3973897879405337e-13,145,161416448,2.3973897879405337e-13,161,137987392,4.522104912751956e-12,329,673019904,5.005440506522518e-12
28050,351,5276736,0.0,526,2377962816,2.0602963779481342e-13,267,393168512,2.0602963779481342e-13,331,340510400,1.5625001292818297e-12,536,1421381440,1.0385581283856027e-12
46200,717,5440640,0.0,919,4023656768,1.7456302770060798e-13,572,982174400,1.7456302770060798e-13,586,868043328,2.065001965601052e-13,1164,3256829376,2.1671553440683056e-13
53625,603,8733760,0.0,1037,4427867392,1.3610126132002599e-12,356,393889536,1.3610126132002599e-12,397,335332800,3.082756272476672e-12,655,1417060032,3.69435487132549e-12
107250,1190,11928704,0.0,2115,8849081792,1.602929398391429e-13,714,781126080,1.602929398391429e-13,789,664504704,6.146194664324867e-12,1263,2649629568,1.0741962874760702e-11
112200,1418,8881344,0.0,2162,9500412480,1.9285668241123054e-13,1072,1560629184,1.9285668241123054e-13,1329,1350389184,7.853717676198357e-13,2008,5013442560,1.2035715503887456e-12
429000,4927,16679744,0.0,21572,35376827136,7.673861546209082e-13,2943,3105610624,4.121147867408581e-13,3305,2638632640,1.0660750060509372e-11,8276,9604215872,1.01527120044409e-11
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmode=log,
    ymode=log,
    width=\textwidth,
    height=0.5\textwidth,
    legend style={at={(0,1)},xshift=0.2cm, yshift=-0.2cm,anchor=north west,nodes=right},
    xlabel={Parameters},
    ylabel={Memory},
    yticklabel={\SI[round-mode=figures,exponent-to-prefix=true,scientific-notation=engineering,zero-decimal-to-integer=true]{\fpeval{exp(\tick)}}{\byte}},
    log y ticks with fixed point/.style={
      yticklabel={
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
        \pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}%
        \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed relative, precision=3]{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
      }
  }
]
\addplot+[mark options={scale=0.5}] table [x expr=\thisrow{x}, y expr=\thisrow{enzyme_memory}, col sep=comma] {gmm.csv};
\addplot+[mark options={scale=0.5}] table [x expr=\thisrow{x}, y expr=\thisrow{torch_memory}, col sep=comma] {gmm.csv};
\addplot+[mark options={scale=0.5}] table [x expr=\thisrow{x}, y expr=\thisrow{impala_memory}, col sep=comma] {gmm.csv};
\addplot+[mark options={scale=0.5}, style={gray, densely dashed}] table [x expr=\thisrow{x}, y expr=\thisrow{manual_memory}, col sep=comma] {gmm.csv};

\addlegendentry{Enzyme}
\addlegendentry{PyTorch}
\addlegendentry{Thorin AD}
\addlegendentry{Manual}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete document. It seem that in it preamble are definitions for colors, table of plotting data, etc. Without knowing them we can't help you. Sory

Comment: I complemented the code fragment to a compiling latex document.

Comment: Thank you for MWE, but ... do you test it? Still is missed list `mycolor` (no so important= and table doesnt work. It throw error ` `Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file 'data/gmm.csv' in 'search p
ath=.'. In case you intended to provide inline data: maybe TeX screwed up your end-of-lines? Try ``row sep=crcr' and terminate your lines with `\\` `(refer to the pgfplotstable manual for details).`

Comment: Yes, on overleaf.com it works. I cleaned the document now even more to eliminate all bugs.
You can view the output on the following URL: https://www.overleaf.com/read/yqjvtpxpvmnj.

Comment: Sorry, stil not works: error:              7! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfplots@already@computed@legend@node ...\thorin 
                                                  AD};\\\pgfplots@show@small...
`. Where is `thorin` defined?

Comment: \thorin is not further important and the absence of the definition had not influenced the execution on overleaf. Does the document now work or are there still errors on your environment?

Answer (score 2):

There is an undefined command `\thorin`. Using `\addlegendentry{thorin AD}` for now, the labeling will start at 1.

[image: a]

Comment: Can you check out: https://www.overleaf.com/project/63b8122311634d2cceda5c1e
I use overleaf for my thesis and there the behavior is different from your output.

Comment: @Christopher Jung  You are right: Overleaf gives an incorrect result. I think you should refer the problem to their technical support. I am using `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.10) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.11.12)`